# ActiveMQ: Dispatched queue contains more messages then prefetch size

Tags: spring-integration, activemq-classic, spring-integration-dsl

I have prefetch size set to 1 (jms.prefetchPolicy.all=1 in url). In web console I can see that prefetch is 1 for all of my consumers. One consumer got stuck and there were 67 messages on his dispatch queue -see my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwdj8.png)

Could you help me understand how could it happen? I've read plenty of articles on this and my understanding is that Dispatch queue size should be up to prefetch size?!

I use following configuration to consume messages from queue:

```
ConnectionFactory getActiveMQConnectionFactory() {
    // Configure the ActiveMQConnectionFactory
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setUserName(user);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setPassword(password);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setNonBlockingRedelivery(true);

    // Configure the redeliver policy and the dead letter queue
    RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
    redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(initialRedeliveryDelay);
    redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(redeliveryDelay);
    redeliveryPolicy.setUseExponentialBackOff(useExponentialBackOff);
    redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(maximumRedeliveries);
    RedeliveryPolicyMap redeliveryPolicyMap = activeMQConnectionFactory.getRedeliveryPolicyMap();
    redeliveryPolicyMap.put(new ActiveMQQueue(thumbnailQueue), redeliveryPolicy);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
    return activeMQConnectionFactory;
}

public IntegrationFlow createThumbnailFlow(String concurrency, CreateThumbnailReceiver receiver) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                    Jms.container(getActiveMQConnectionFactory(), thumbnailQueue)
                            .concurrency(concurrency)
                            .sessionTransacted(true)
                            .get()
            ))
            .transform(new JsonToObjectTransformer(CreateThumbnailRequest.class, jsonObjectMapper()))
            .handle(receiver)
            .get();
}
```

Comment: What is your client code doing?  Provide more details please

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will put more details shortly. Could you tell me if (in general) my understanding is good - dispatched queue’s size should be linited to prefetch size?

Comment: Not really, depends on what you are doing.  Client ACK or transactions can exhibit this behaviour

Comment: I have added code I use to consume messages from jms.

Comment: Is anybody able to explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was cause by difference between version of broker (5.14.5) and client (5.15.3). After upgrading broker dispatched queue contains at most 2 message as expected.